# Package Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0 not found

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, qtgstreamer

Did anybody got the luck to know the reason for:
"Project ERROR: Package Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0 not found".

I have installed: qt-gstreamer-dev package
Not working even after manually adding PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR:
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/manojsahu/qt-gstreamer-1.2.0/src/QGst/QtGStreamer-1.0.pc.in

I have also added PKGCONFIG alternatively in .pro file like:
PKGCONFIG += Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0
PKGCONFIG += QtGStreamer-1.0

Can anybody help to resolve this error.
I am trying to compile example in below mentioned link:

https://github.com/detrout/qt-gstreamer/tree/master/examples/qmlplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I have got one work around to solve "Project ERROR: Package Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0 not found".

1. "Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0" has dependency with "gstreamer-1".
   Download "gstreamer-1.6.3" and perform 
   **make** then
   **make install**.
2. Download the qt-gstreamer code, extract freshly and navigate to extracted folder. In my case it is

   cd ~/home/manojsahu/qt-gstreamer-1.2.0/
   **cmake CMakeLists.txt** then
   **make** then
   **sudo make** **install** 
   [Image of the qmlplayer built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXV8E.png)

Now the example qmlplayer gets built. 
But facing error "Failed to create qtvideosink. Make sure it is installed correctly".
Perhaps It did not installed properly. Any workaround to build completely would be appreciated highly.